# C++ subsequent files fail to open after first file

Tags: c++, loops, getfiles

After the program reads the file, gets characters from the file, and finishes, the user is asked if they want another file read or not.  If the user say yes, then the program asks for the file name, but then automatically says the file could not be opened and exits the loop. Please help me.

Here is the code:

```
do //do while opening the source file fails
      {
         cout << "Enter filename of source file: ";
         cin.getline (filename,51);
         sourceFile.open(filename);  //opens the file with given filename
         if (sourceFile.fail())
            cout << "File could not be opened" << endl;  //error if can't open
         sourceFile.clear();
      } 
      while (sourceFile.fail());  //exits if source file doesn't fail
```

Comment: Did you try a debugger?  Did the filename you tried to open make sense?

Comment: what is a good debugger?

Comment: What error do you get?  What system are you running on?  `gdb` is a popular debugger, but what you use will depend on what system you're using.

Comment: did you try `.close()` the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This test:

```
while (sourceFile.fail())
```

will never be true because just before you get there you call:

```
sourceFile.clear()
```

which will clear any problem bits in the `iostate` for the stream.

I think you just want to get rid of the call to `clear()`.

Comment: well it works because the first file opens fine when it runs throught this do while loop

Comment: @TylerGavin: I thought the problem was that if the open failed the loop didn't go around to ask for a filename again.

Comment: @TylerGavin: I think I see now - I believe that what I have in this answer is a problem in your code (if the open fails, you get no chance to try again, which is what I think the intent of the loop is). However, it sounds like your immediate problem is solved by arminb's comment.

Answer (score 0):

The canonical way to check if opening the file failed is to use [**`std::basic_ios::operator !()`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator!):

```
do
{
    cout << "Enter filename of source file: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, filename);
    sourceFile.open(filename.c_str());
    if (!sourceFile)
    {
        cout << "File could not be opened" << endl;
    }
}
while (!sourceFile);
```